# How to count from a sentence in C#

Tags: c#

So, I am creating a word filter for a game server in C# and basically I am trying to scourer the sentence for banned words and replace them with clean words. I've already done so, but now I'm up to the part where I want to scan the sentence for a list of sentence banned words. I'm hopeless at this bit, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Basically I am `CheckSentence(Message)` in the ChatManager, and need the following code to count and return `continue;` if the value is more than 5. So far I have:

```
public bool CheckSentence(string Message)
    {
        foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
        {
            if (Message.ToLower().Contains(Filter.Word) && Filter.IsSentence)
            {
                // count Message, if message contains >5 
               // from (Message.Contains(Filter.Word))
              // continue; else (ignore)

            }

        }
            return false;
    }
```

I'm not too sure if that makes much sense, but I want it to continue; if there are more than 5 `Message.Contains(Filter.Word)`

Comment: Excuse me @MitchWheat

Comment: Have you tried splitting the message into individual words and counting the number of words that match your filter?

Comment: I'm unaware of how to do so, which is why I'm asking the community for help. I'm self taught, and I'm still learning how to do things. This being a major thing I've been stuck on for a while now @casablanca

Comment: @Liam: profanity filters don't work: see scunthorpe

Comment: @MitchWheat yes it will, because I'm blocking advertisers from coming on my site advertising other sites and it's worked very well so far. Now all I need to do is scan the sentence for words, if the sentence contains more than 5 words that is in the filter's table, it will ban them automatically :) Sentences can only contain up to  100 letters, so if 5 of those words are banned (which will be almost 20 letters, roughly) then they're most likely advertising.

Comment: "and it's worked very well so far" - so you don't have a problem?

Comment: I'm using a word filter, which is filtering certain words that are banned and replacing them with **** for example. And if the word is a bannable offence word, then they will be banned after 5 sayings. NOW MY THREAD is asking for help with a SENTENCE FILTER. I want to scan the sentence, and if that one given sentence contains 5 banned words, I WANT TO BAN THEM. I don't think you understand my question, and your remarks aren't very helpful in this situation. @MitchWheat

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you give us example data

Comment: I would ask what type is your _filteredWords? because I see you casting it to List. If you predefined the type, it would be better performance as a HashSet<string>.
I also suggest iterating through the smaller "List" of words from the message against the "List" from _filteredWords, then the other way around (which you did), for less processing.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public bool CheckSentence(string rawMessage)
    {
        var lower = rawMessage.ToLower();
        var count = 0;

        foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
        {
            if (lower.Contains(Filter.Word) && Filter.IsSentence)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count >= 5;
    }
```

If this becomes too slow, you may be better of caching the list of filtered words in a HashSet, and iterating over each word in the message, checking if it exists in the HashSet, which would give you O(n) speed, where N is the number of words.

### LINQ Version

```
    public bool CheckSentenceLinq(string rawMessage)
    {
        var lower = rawMessage.ToLower();

        return _filteredWords
                   .Where(x => x.IsSentence)
                   .Count(x => lower.Contains(x.Word)) >= 5;
    }
```

### EDIT 2: LINQ Updated As per [@S.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442466/s-c) Comment

By [@S.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442466/s-c)

> For the linq version, there's no need to count past the first five. return _filteredWords.Where(x => x.IsSentence && lower.Contains(x.Word)).Skip(5).Any();

```
    public bool CheckSentenceLinq(string rawMessage)
    {
        var lower = rawMessage.ToLower();

        return _filteredWords
                   .Where(x => x.IsSentence)
                   .Where(x => lower.Contains(x.Word))
                   .Skip(5)
                   .Any();
    }
```

## ToUpper vs ToLower

As @DevEstacion mentioned and per Microsoft [best practices for using string recommendations here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx) it is best to use `ToUpperInvariant()` for string comparisons rather than `ToLowerInvariant()`.

### EDIT:Using Continue

```
    public bool CheckSentenceWithContinue(string rawMessage)
    {
        var lower = rawMessage.ToLower();
        var count = 0;

        foreach (WordFilter Filter in this._filteredWords.ToList())
        {
            if (!Filter.IsSentence)
                continue; // Move on to the next filter, as this is not a senetece word filter

            if (!lower.Contains(Filter.Word))
                continue; // Move on to the next filter, as the message does not contain this word

            // If you are here it means filter is a Sentence filter, and the message contains the word, so increment the counter
            count++;
        }

        return count >= 5;
    }
```

Comment: It could be better if you'd make the Filter.Word to lowercase aswell. Also, ToUpper is faster :)

Comment: @DevEstacion I was assuming his filter words are already stored in lower...

Comment: Would return count >= 5; be the same as if I were to continue;?

Comment: no because the `return count >= 5`, is not inside a `foreach` block, so there is nothing to continue on. `continue` is used when you want to skip to the next iteration inside a `foreach` loop. Where as here, inside the loop you are counting the number of words.

Comment: see last edit, for how you could use continue

Comment: For the linq version, there's no need to count past the first five.
    
`return _filteredWords.Where(x => x.IsSentence && lower.Contains(x.Word)).Skip(5).Any();`

Comment: My point was that your iterating over the filter list, which is why you continue if you find a match, but it is much faster to iterate over the message against the filter list. 
   @MichalCiechan Also (maybe wrong as not don't have complete understanding of performance syntax of O(N) ) but isn't Contains against a HashSet O(1) and against a list O(N)?

Comment: So would it still be a public bool? Because now I'm trying to use the function VIA `if (PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetChatManager().GetFilter().CheckSentence(Message))
            {
                Session.SendWhisper("You cheeky fkr");
            }` And it's not returning the whisper. I also tried doing if the count is more than 5 to return true, but still nothing?

Comment: @Edward doing a single contains in the HashSet is O(1) (e.g. single word in message), but as you can have N words in the message it will be O(1 * N), which = O(N). But considering OP mentioned the message is limited to a relatively small number of characters such as 260? (can't find it right now) the N words inside a message can be probably ignored.

Comment: @S.C. +1 Yes you are definitely correct, although by far the biggest improvement would be putting the filter words inside the HashSet, and splitting the message into words and checking against the HashSet

Comment: @Liam are you sure your `_filteredWords` collection is correctly set up and normalised to lower characters already? You have to either make sure all your filter words are in lower case, or use a comparison which ignores case such as: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(lower, Filter.Word, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

I believe someone already posted a correct answer, I'm just here to provide an alternative.

So instead of doing a `forloop` or `foreach`, I'll be providing you with Regex solution.

```
public bool CheckSentence(string rawMessage)
{
    /*
        The string.Join("|", _filteredWords) will create the pattern for the Regex
        the '|' means or so from the list of filtered words, it will look it up on
        the raw message and get all matches
    */
    return new Regex(string.Join("|", _filteredWords.Where(x => x.IsSentence)), 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled).Match(rawMessage).Length >= 5;
}
```

Benefits? much shorter, prevents loop and could be faster :)

Don't forget to add these two lines of using declaration on top of the .cs file

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: You mention the regex prevents loops, but isn't Join (at least in T-SQL world) just as slow as your joining all possible combinations between the two sets, and therefore "No" faster?

Comment: @Edward yes, string.Join uses for loop underneath. But I'm pertaining to the loop on his method. Regarding faster, we don't know, unless one of us test it.